How to calculate the delta between the previous period and the current period in DAX with an IF
I am trying to calculate in DAX the delta between the previous period (quarter) and the current period, but my formula does not work correctly for each case
I try to calculate the difference between Value and Q-1 Value when there is a result in Value <> 0
Then I try to calculate the difference between the Sale and the Value Q-1 when there is no result in Value = 0
To resume, here the formula explained
if the Value <> 0 => take the current Value - the Value of the previous Quarter
else if the Value = 0 (case of a Sale) => take the sale - the Value of the previous period
I didn't succeed the second part of the if, it only shows the value of the Sale in current quarter
Here is the code I used:
Calculate =
IF (
    SUM ( 'Append'[Value] ) <> 0,
    SUM ( 'Append'[Value] )
        - CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Append'[Value] ),
            PARALLELPERIOD ( 'Append'[DATE_REFERENCE], -1, QUARTER )
        ),
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Append[Sale] ), KEEPFILTERS ( 'Append'[Status] = "Sale" ) )
        - CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Append'[Value] ),
            PARALLELPERIOD ( 'Append'[DATE_REFERENCE], -1, QUARTER )
        )
)


if the Value <> 0 => take the current Value - the Value of the previous Quarter

if the Value = 0 (case of a Sale) => take the sale - the Value of the previous period```


Here is the result :



Code
DATE_REFERENCE
Status
Sale
Value
Calculate




30
31/12/2023
Value
0
756527
-


30
31/03/2024
Value
0
756527
-


30
30/06/2024
Value
0
815173
58646


31
31/12/2023
Value
0
557133
-


31
31/03/2024
Sale
-475000
0
-475000


31
30/06/2024
Value
0
0
-


32
31/12/2023
Value
0
351873
-


32
31/03/2024
Value
0
351873
-


32
30/06/2024
Sale
-300000
0
-300000



Here is the result I would have :



Code
DATE_REFERENCE
Status
Sale
Value
Calculate




30
31/12/2023
Value
0
756527
-


30
31/03/2024
Value
0
756527
-


30
30/06/2024
Value
0
815173
58646


31
31/12/2023
Value
0
557133
-


31
31/03/2024
Sale
-475000
0
82133


31
30/06/2024
Value
0
0
-


32
31/12/2023
Value
0
351873
-


32
31/03/2024
Value
0
351873
-


32
30/06/2024
Sale
-300000
0
51873



Could you please help me ?
Many thanks in advance

Using the code sent by Michal, I tested different formulas and now it works,
I added the line "ALLSELECTED('Append')" followed by the line "PARALLELPERIOD('Append'[DATE_REFERENCE], -1, QUARTER)"
This line allows me to select all the values, even those that were previously filtered and not retrieved by "PARALLELPERIOD"
Here is the code
CalculateMeasure = 
VAR CurrentValue = SUM('Append'[Value])
VAR CurrentSale = SUM('Append'[Sale])
VAR PreviousQuarterValue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Append'[Value]),
        ALLSELECTED('Append'),
        PARALLELPERIOD('Append'[DATE_REFERENCE], -1, QUARTER)
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        CurrentValue <> 0,
        CurrentValue - PreviousQuarterValue,
        IF (
            CurrentValue = 0,
            CurrentSale - PreviousQuarterValue,
            BLANK()
        )
    )


You seem to have made a mistake with either your explanation or the output table, I have implemented your stated algorythm

if the Value < > 0 = > take the current Value - the Value of the previous Quarter
if the Value = 0 (case of a Sale) = > take the sale - the Value of the previous period

and it works out very different to the output you have shown in the second table.
CalculateMeasure = 
VAR CurrentValue = SUM('Append'[Value])
VAR CurrentSale = SUM('Append'[Sale])
VAR PreviousQuarterValue = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Append'[Value]),
        PARALLELPERIOD('Append'[DATE_REFERENCE], -1, QUARTER)
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        CurrentValue <> 0,
        CurrentValue - PreviousQuarterValue,
        IF (
            CurrentValue = 0,
            CurrentSale - PreviousQuarterValue,
            BLANK()
        )
    )



Many thanks for your help and the code improved
"and it works out very different to the output you have shown in the second table"
The 2nd table is a manually created one with correct results
My problem is that in the last row (date 30/06/2024 and code 32) the result shouldn't be -300000, it should be 51873.
CurrentSale + PreviousQuarterValue = -300000 + 351873 = 51873
Samething for the row 31/03/2024 and code 31, the result shouldn't be -475000, it should be 82133.
CurrentSale + PreviousQuarterValue = -475000 + 557133 = 82133
Do you understand what I’m trying to explain?
